# Executing raw SQL using EntityFrameworkCore and SQLite on .NET Core

Tags: entity-framework, sqlite, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I am working on some security illustrations and therefore need to purposefully write insecure SQL queries.

The environment I am looking at is .NET Core (not full .NET), the driver used is EntityFrameworkCore and the database type is SQLite.

Regular connections using the built in lookup and query functions work without any issue. However there seems to be no function that would allow me to execute a raw SQL statement.

Several online resources recommend using the `.FromSql()` and `.SqlQuery()` methods on the database / context, but neither of these methods seems to exist in the .NET Core driver.

Is there any way to execute a raw SQL query in this setting?

Comment: Did you take a look at [this documentation page](http://ef.readthedocs.io/en/latest/querying/raw-sql.html)?

Comment: Yes, that is where my attempt to use .FromSql() comes from. It seems to only be available for full .NET however.

Comment: Did you add the required using statement? They are extension methods

Comment: Added Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc and Microsoft.Data.Sqlite. Am I missing one?

Comment: Did you try to use it like this : `dbContext.SampleEntities.FromSql(sqlStr)`? And did you add `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite` to package.json.

Comment: Yes. 'DbSet<Message>' does not contain a definition for 'FromSql' and no extension method 'FromSql' accepting a first argument of type 'DbSet<Message>' could be found.

Comment: `FromSql`extension method is in `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational` assembly and `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite` depends on it. So if you install sqlite package you can use `FromSql` extension method. I tested it and there is no problem. See references tab and check if there is `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite` reference.

Comment: You are awesome :) For some reason nuget failed to pull in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational in my case. Installed it manually and everything works. If you could post your answer covering the dependencies in Answer format, I'll up vote and accept (y)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed at comment:

Check if there is `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational` reference on your project references(if you use sqllite it should be in the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite` reference).

Comment: Using `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite` 6.0.2 which contains `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational`, but still no luck. None of the methods for raw queries exists. Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Nuget Package:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite

and

```
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("YOUR SQLITE SQL COMMAND");
```

where db is an instance of a class derived from DbContext

Comment: How to obtain data returned by this function? It returns number of affected rows, not data

Comment: ExecuteSqlCommand is now obsolete, use ExecuteSqlRaw and ExecuteSqlRawAsync, FromSqlRaw instead. Search for "ef core breaking changes"